# Could providing 3V instead of 3.3V have damaged my OLED Screen Module?

Tags: oled

I'm a beginner trying to attach an [OLED screen module](https://www.waveshare.com/1.5inch-oled-module.htm) made by Waveshare ([schematic](https://www.waveshare.net/w/upload/a/a3/1.5inch_RGB_OLED_Module_Schematic.pdf), [datasheet of OLED screen](https://www.waveshare.net/w/upload/c/c3/1.5inch_OLED_Specification.pdf)) to my nRF5340 DK devkit (schematic sadly only available as part of a .zip file [here](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-hardware/nRF5340-DK/Download#infotabs)) via SPI, but the display gives me dark horizontal lines of moving across it, even when set to full on white. Capturing it on video or photo is difficult:

[image: Image of blurry lines]

Connection of Board (see page 5 of schematics) -> OLED display:

- P7.4 -> VCC
- P7.7 -> GND
- P5.3 -> DIN
- P5.4 -> CLK
- P3.7 -> CS
- P3.6 -> DC
- P3.5 -> RST

Image of entire setup:
[image: Image of the entire setup]

Close-up of Waveshare OLED Board backside:

[image: Backside of OLED module]

As configuration data for the display I'm sending exactly what waveshare had in their sample code and as far as I could tell with a logic analyzer, this data is correct.

The only thing I'm aware of doing that may be out of spec is that my devkit is only providing 3V, instead of the minimum of 3.3V Waveshare lists on their website. Could this have damaged the display?

Trying to use it with an arduino afterwards with exactly the Waveshare sample code also led to the weird lines / flickering.

**Update**

I had a temporary fluke success where the display was fine after turning it over to look for whether I could probe the 15V line of the display cable, so my current hypothesis is that this may be a wiring issue. I will solder a pin header on the other side of the display tomorrow and get back to you.

**Thank you all very much so far :)**

Comment: I think an undervoltage of 0.3V is unlikely to have damaged your OLED, except perhaps if the I/O pins were driven higher than the power rail voltage. Was that the case?

Comment: I don't think so, I just re-measured CS and VCC and both were almost exactly at 3V

Comment: Where's the pdf data sheet for the LCD module? Note that items with only descriptions provided by web-pages leave you with no ability to track changes made by the supplier. This means that quality suffers and your LCD could easily be regarded as sub-standard materiel even when bought new. However, if you can provide a data sheet link....

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for pointing that out, I forgot to link that as well. It's https://www.waveshare.net/w/upload/c/c3/1.5inch_OLED_Specification.pdf, I now also added it to the question.

Comment: You do not show your actual power supply or specs. for Vcc and 3.3V  . Please update with more accuracy, photo , datasheet, whatever

Comment: Wild speculation: the display **is** displaying full on white, but some power supply fluctuations are causing the amount of white to be different for each pixel. Look at the pattern: assuming the screen scans from top to bottom, the pixels are getting dimmer and then suddenly getting bright again. That looks exactly like power supply ripple! Try adding more capacitance?

Comment: On the Waveshare schematic, the voltages applied to the VDD and VCI pins are reversed compared with the RitDisplay application circuit, but in any case, this is not the exact schematic because it's for a 30-pin module and yours has only 25 pins!

Comment: i stronly suggest you replace those janky breadboard wires with solid copper 20 or 22AWG wire.

Answer (score 4):

Where's the pdf data sheet for the LCD module?

> *@Andyaka Thanks for pointing that out, I forgot to link that as well.
> It's [waveshare.net/w/upload/c/c3/1.5inch_OLED_Specification.pdf](https://www.waveshare.net/w/upload/c/c3/1.5inch_OLED_Specification.pdf)*

Here's a section from the data sheet: -

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the power supply (\$V_{CI}\$) level can be from 2.6 volts to 3.5 volts so, maybe you forgot to provide the \$V_{CC}\$ supply of nominally 15 volts? Both supplies are needed but, as I can see in your schematic, it looks like you have provided the 15 volts via a boost converter.

> *The only thing I'm aware of doing that may be out of spec is that my
> devkit is only providing 3V, instead of the minimum of 3.3V Waveshare
> lists on their website. Could this have damaged the display?*

No, that doesn't seem likely.

Comment: I'm using a premade OLED Module / Board which has only a single voltage input pin, the voltage regulation is handled by it as well, so I don't have any control over that.

Comment: Try measuring the 15 volts to see that it is within spec @Andreas

Comment: I'm not sure whether I can probe on this fine display connector without shorting something, but after looking at it, I had a fluke attempt where after turning on the display again it did not have the travelling lines and also didn't whine. Could this behaviour also be caused by an intermittent power connection?

Comment: @Andreas I don't see why not; most other random bad behaviours are easily caused by bad connections.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal lines look like power supply ripple. Assuming the screen scans from top to bottom, the pixels are getting dimmer and then suddenly getting bright again. Which is the sort of waveform you would expect from power supply ripple.

I gather that the display uses an 8-19V high voltage supply for the display, and the Waveshare circuit board has a boost converter which provides this. In which case, is there something wrong with the output capacitor? I can't tell which component that is.

You say that it worked after fiddling with the module a bit - perhaps a cracked solder joint making intermittent contact?

The whining noise could also be a symptom of a problem with the boost converter. Usually they run at a frequency too high to hear, but if the output current is too low, they will reduce the frequency and run in so-called "burst mode".

Or perhaps the Waveshare module is struggling to get power itself for the converter. You could check the voltage at the input pins - is it enough?

Long wires can sometimes have too much inductance for reliable high-frequency operation - essentially when the module draws power the power can't get there fast enough and the voltage drops. You can try adding more capacitance directly at the power input of the Waveshare board, although boost converters should have reasonably steady input current so I think this is unlikely to be the problem.

Either way, in my opinion all signs point to a power supply problem. If you have an oscilloscope you can try to probe the 8-19V power supply of the display. I bet it's got too low a voltage and too much ripple.